# Android Studio getPixel of CameraX Bitmap error (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bitmap, android-camerax

I made an android app (Android Studio + Kotlin) that uses CameraX. So this is my code to start the camera:

```
private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview
                )

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
```

Now I wanted to get a bitmap of the viewFinder so that I can determine the color of the pixel in the center:

```
val bitmap = viewFinder.bitmap
val pixel = bitmap?.getPixel(width / 2, height / 2 - 30)

val pixel2 = if (pixel != null) pixel else -1
```

bitmap is `Bitmap?` and pixel is `Int?`

When I run the app everything works completely fine but then sometimes it crashes and shoots out this message:

```
at com.example.colorblind.MainActivity$onCreate$r$1.run(MainActivity.kt:116)
```

Line 116 is the line with `val pixel = bitmap?.getPixel(width / 2, height / 2 - 30)`. If I then add a line before the code so that it hops to line 117 everything works perfectly fine again until the same error occurs. Then I need to change the line again. How can I fix this problem because I can't publish the app like this if it sometimes randomly crashes while opening.

I hope I was able to explain the problem properly.

EDIT

This is the only message I get when it crashes:

```
2022-02-16 20:43:53.123 7337-7337/com.example.colorblind E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.colorblind, PID: 7337
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1958)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1863)
        at com.example.colorblind.MainActivity$onCreate$r$1.run(MainActivity.kt:116)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: "*sometimes it crashes and shoots out this error [...]*" - this **isn't** an error. This is just a place where the error occurred. Pleast post the full error message.

Comment: oh you're completely right let me look for the error message. thanks mate

Comment: I hope this edit was helpful :)

Comment: Where do you compute `height`? The error indicated that the expression `height / 2 - 30` somehow results in a greater value than `bitmap.height`.

Comment: sorry for my late reply but I implemented it like this: ```val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels``` ```val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels```

Comment: And are you certain that your `displayMetrics.heightPixels` is less than `bitmap.height`? Have you tried logging `bitmap.height` and the resulting value of `height / 2 - 30`?

Comment: so i think that `displayMetrics.heightPixels` is more than `bitmap.height` I'll test it with this really quick

Comment: well if I use `bitmap.height` the value height gets an `Int?` so I can't use it as the parameter for get pixel

Comment: Make the call null-safe and you will be able to do so. For example using `bitmap?.run { ... }`.

Comment: now i added it like this: `val pixel = bitmap?.getPixel(bitmap.width / 2, bitmap.height / 2)` and i think its working

Comment: Glad it helped :)